# Is a hidden token field not insecure?

Tags: php, forms, token

I am completely new to PHP and wanted to make my form more secure. By googling I found that I should insert a hidden field in the form, like this `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ?>`. But isn't that unsafe?
If I now inspect the field with the chrome developper tool, then I see the token as plain text. Is that bad?
 Also, method htmlentities() should be used for user input. Should this also be done for the token? For example : `value="<?php echo htmlentities($token) ?>"`

Comment: A form field is neither inherently secure nor insecure.  Security matters when you *do something* with that data.  What are you doing with that data?

Comment: why dont you used encryption in input field

Comment: The token is usually a regular string, so htmlentities is unnecessary. That's only for outputting to the browser.

Comment: @David 
I just send it to another php file and validate there if the user has filled out the contact form correctly and if the token matches. If the user has filled out the form correctly and the token matches, an email will be sent. That's all

Comment: @Umair Mubeen
I don't know? I've never heard of it before.As I said, I'm completely new to PHP and also a complete beginner in security. And I never saw the encryption in any tutorial

Comment: @Sud0: Define "unsafe" then.  Can the user edit that value?  Yes.  If they do, will it match when compared with the original?  Nope.  So the server would presumably return an error and not process the input.  What security concern do you have?

Comment: The user fills in only one contact form and this is validated on the server side (if it is filled in correctly). I have only done one tutorial and this token was used. But i think i don't need the token when i read the Post from 0xrishabh.

Comment: Side note: If you are making a contact form which emails someone on form submit, you may want to add a "honeypot" to also reject/silent error on.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for that hint IncredibleHat. I will do that too

Answer (score 1):

Generally, tokens in forms are used for protecting against [csrf](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) attacks.
And no, it's not unsafe because the only user who can see the token is the one using it.

No, you don't need to use htmlentities() for a token if you are creating it on the server without taking user input in it.

*Note*: Make sure the token is bind to session cause otherwise the user B potentially can use his token to submit form of user A if user A visits his website by sending a GET/POST request.to the form with predefined values.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I was just doing a tutorial and they used this token. So that means that the token is not necessary in my scenario? I'm just making a website (1 page) where the user only fills in a contact form. This is then sent by ajax to my validation.php file (if javascript is not turned off). Here I do the server side validation if the user has filled out the form correctly. So csrf is only possible if there is a session respectively the user can log in to the website. So for my scenario the token is unnecessary.